# Xcode fails to run tests

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode7.1

After upgrading to Xcode 7.1 yesterday, I got a new bug (yay!). When I try to run a test by clicking on the test diamond icon, it builds, "runs", nothing actually runs and the test passes after a second. Also when I run tests with cmd-u.

Does anybody have the same problem? Do you know a workaround? I tried closing Xcode, rebooting, rebuilding, nothing fixed it.

The notification says "Test succeded (null)".

Comment: I had something somewhat similar and restarts of Xcode didn't work. Killing and restarting Xcode AND the simulator helped me.

Comment: Thanks @Logan, killed Xcode and restarted device (not using simulator) and now working again. What we have to do, just to be able to _work_...

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure what causes it, I think it has something to do with stopping a test early, but I can't regularly reproduce it.  Gotten into the bad state a couple of times.

Comment: I stop tests frequently, I debug/test while writing code, so yeah it might be the cause. Also every time you stop, Xcode writes a log to disk, which for me ends to be gigabytes after a few days O_o